# PHP + Curl: Login with enctype multipart/form-data

Tags: php, forms, curl

I'm using php and curl and I have some problems with a form with `enctype=multipart/form-data`.

the form in the remote web page:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/account/login" id="login">
<label for="username">Username</label><input name="username" id="username"><br>
<label for="password">Password</label><input name="password" id="password" type="password"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="keeplogged" id="keeplogged" value="on"><label for="keeplogged">Remember me</label><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

the `post` data (from Firefox):

```
POSTDATA =-----------------------------24464570528145
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

fakeuser
-----------------------------24464570528145
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

fakepass
-----------------------------24464570528145
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="keeplogged"

on
-----------------------------24464570528145
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"

Submit
-----------------------------24464570528145--
```

and I'm trying to do a login with curl:

```
function login($ref)
{
// Identify the URL:
$url = 'http://www.fakeSite.com/account/login';

$dt = array();
$dt['username'] = 'fakeUser';
$dt['password'] = 'fakePass';
$dt['keeplogged'] = 'on';
$dt['submit'] = 'Submit';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dt);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl))//If there is any error
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    exit();
}

curl_close($curl);

return $result;
}
```

but the result is nothing! No result, no errors, nothing! Anyone have any idea?

PS: I have tried to pass the postfields formatted like the one from Firefox, but this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Do you get any output if you add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of your script and then run it?

Answer (score 0):

I got some problems with API using `enctype=multipart/form-data` (Proxmox VE).

Try to add your `POST` datas using a string instead of an array (with `http_build_query`) :

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($dt));
```

Comment: I have already tried, nothing... if you can think something else I will be very thankful :)

Comment: Can you do a <?php var_dump($_POST); ?> on the destination page, and then a var dump of your function var_dump(login("your infos")); ?

Comment: unfortunately I have no control on the destination page, its a external site ( I have to scrape a products list ) and I have NO idea on how they parse the data.

Comment: Maybe they dissalow some user agents ... Try changing the user agent of your cURL client, we can try by using firefox 13 :
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1");

Comment: thx for the help! I tried and nothing has changed, i hate it when there are no message for debug!

Comment: Hum, i have no more idea ... Are you sure you are posting all datas ? (no token on the submit form ?)

Comment: no... I'm pretty sure, i have seen the data sent by firefox with Tamper Data and there is nothing more.

Comment: Hum ... I think i cant help you more ... Sorry